# Highcharts not running in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: highcharts

I built a line chart in Highcharts and it works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer 11: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/7semj2yz/8/)

```
data: {
googleSpreadsheetKey: '1QZV65cwN-eSjDoX6pw1OEuOwP8fR-B95AtfkeK5ts2E' },
```

Only the select menu is displayed:

[image: empty chart]

What could cause this problem?

Comment: It seems that there is an arrow function in your code which is not supported in the IE11. Try to render the chart without it.

Comment: Could you give me a hint where I can find this function?

Comment: in the `dataLabels.formatter` callback - line 229